# Arranging multiple columns menu in 1 row

Tags: html, css

I have a menu which has multiple columns ( [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/Ff5MV/) ). I found that if I continue to add more columns or resize the browser to have less width, the menu columns will go to 2nd row. It is due to the CSS attribute `float: left;`.

**CSS**

```
#menus {
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
#menus .menu {
    border: 1px solid #00F;
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Since HTML codes are quite long, see jsFiddle for more information.

How can I arrange the menu in 1 row ( without changing to 2nd row ) without fixing it's absolute positions of each column ? It is preferred not to rely on JavaScript on layout, though jQuery will be used on other parts of the website.

Note: Please consider cross-browser compatibility. Support of IE 6 or above is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

though it is not the optimized solution but you can use :

```
#menus {
    border: 1px solid #F00; white-space:nowrap;

}
#menus .menu {
    border: 1px solid #00F;
    /*float: left;*/ display:inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Promising solution. Still checking if there is any drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use This Css if you want to show all menu in one row.

```
 #menus {
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    display: table;
    }
    #menus .menu {
    border: 1px solid #00F;
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

If you want fulwidth menu you can use

```
   #menus {
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#menus .menu {
    border: 1px solid #00F;
    display:table-cell;
    min-width: 18%;
    height: 100%;    
}
```

Comment: `display: table` requires IE8 or above to support. I plan to support as many browsers as possible.

Comment: #menu {width:1414px}; try it

Comment: Do not copy other's answer into your answer. Thanks for your suggestion though.